# Gulp not creating CSS folder on production build

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a static site that uses two gulpfiles to compile. One is `gulpfile.dev.js` which compiles all the files correctly and uses a static server served by browsersync. The `gulpfile.prod.js` is the the exact same as the dev file, just without browsersync server. When I compile my file using DeployHQ to move files on my server it doesn't compile the necessary `css` folder.

My `gulpfile.prod.js` file:

```
//DH
var gulp = require('gulp'),                       //Task runner
    uglify       = require('gulp-uglify'),        //Minimizies JS
    sass         = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),     //Compiles to CSS
    imagemin     = require('gulp-imagemin'),      // Minimize images
    concat       = require('gulp-concat'),
    concatCss    = require('gulp-concat-css'),
    gutil        = require('gulp-util'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    cssnano      = require('gulp-cssnano'),
    pug          = require('gulp-pug'),
    htmlmin      = require('gulp-htmlmin');

// Define paths for sources and destination.
var paths = {
  src: {
    js: './src/js/*.js',
    sass: './src/sass/**/*.sass',
    html: './views/*.pug'
  },

  dest: {
    js: './app/build/js',
    css: './app/build/css',
    html: './app'
  }

};

var autoprefixerOptions = {
  browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 5%', 'Firefox ESR']
};

//Error look-outs in gulp
function errorLog(error){
  console.error.bind(error);
  this.emit('end');
}

// Scripts
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  gulp.src(paths.src.js)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .on('error', errorLog)
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest.js))
});

// PUG -> HTML
gulp.task('pug', function buildHTML() {
  return gulp.src(paths.src.html)
  .pipe(pug())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest.html))
  .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}));
});

// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function(){
  return sass(paths.src.sass)
  .on('error', errorLog)
  .pipe(autoprefixer(autoprefixerOptions))
  .pipe(cssnano())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest.css))
});

//Run task
gulp.task('default', [
  'scripts',
  'pug',
  'styles']);
```

These are the `bash` commands DeployHQ executes to serve the files correctly in the right directory. Most of it is just removing files that I don't need to be on the server. I build the files needed to be served from `app/` then move the files to the root html directory. `nam run prod` translates to `gulp default --gulpfile gulpfile.prod.js`

```
cd /var/www/site.com/html
npm install
npm run prod
rm -rf node_modules/ src/ views/
cd app
cp -a build/ /var/www/site.com/html
cp index.html /var/www/site.com/html
cd ..
rm -rf app/
rm .gitlab-ci.yml gulpfile.dev.js gulpfile.prod.js package.json .gitignore README.md
```

## Edit:

Running the prod file locally compiles everything as its supposed to, but on the server it does not. It does not compile the css folder.

## Edit 2:

I've changed my styles task to reflect `gulp-ruby-sass`'s documentation to this:

```
gulp.task('styles', function(){
  sass(paths.src.sass)
  .on('error', errorLog)
  .pipe(autoprefixer(autoprefixerOptions))
  .pipe(cssnano())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest.css))
});
```

The CSS folder still does not compile.

Comment: Which host are you using, or are you using any Continous Integration tool?

Comment: @AkinjideBankole I'm using Google Cloud Platform with a Node.js server. The only CI tool would be DeployHQ handling the build process. I host the code on GitLab --> web hook to DeployHQ --> build.

Comment: Can you assess the build logs?

Comment: @AkinjideBankole Yes, nothing of concern happens. Everything builds fine when installing. I tried to limit the amount of tasks in my build script above to where I don't move anything out of `app/` but the css folder still does not build.

Comment: Your sass task is there a reason to why you are returning the stream?

Comment: @AkinjideBankole was following some guides for getting it to work a while back, is there a different way i should try it? Maybe return the gulp source?

Comment: from what I saw on gulp-ruby-sass github page, the `sass()` wasn't returned, you should follow their example

Comment: @AkinjideBankole I've added the changes and updated the post. The folder is still not compiling.